Why is my JavaFX application not recognizing the image file?
I am using JavaFX and Scenebuilder to create a flappybird game with an easy, hard, and normal difficulty. I made two scenes one named titlescreen and one named difficultyselectionscreen in scenebuilder. They are self explanatory. The problem is when I am on the difficultyselectionscreen when I run my App.java, it gives me and error and doesn't run my FlappyBirdEasy class code. I'm pretty sure my controller in scenebuilder is correct but there would be a ton of screenshots if I screenshotted all my code so if someone can please direct message me or comment to help me out that would be great.
I am pretty sure the problem is with my image path as that is what my catch block is saying but my path is correct I'm 99% sure. When I click the Easy button it says this after around 50 lines of errors.
    InputStream birdImageStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/flappybird.png");
    if (birdImageStream == null) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load bird image: InputStream is null");
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load bird image.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bird image loaded successfully");
    }

It gives me the Failed to load bird message.
I tried to fix the image path multiple times but I keep getting this error.

as posted, the images directory must be in one of the directories listed in the CLASSPATH (environment variable or -cp option) - if the CLASSPATH is empty/not given, the actual working directory (where java is started) is used

So it can't just be in the project? It has to be in my package? Not sure if that is what you're saying I don't really understand eclipse that well

getClass().getResousourceAsStream() uses the classpath to search the resources - the resource is /images/flappybird.png so it searches all directories listed on the classpath for all directories called images and a file flappybird.png in each such directory (first found is used). Since the path starts with /, images must be directly in the listed diretories, like a package images; for a relative path, not starting with /, images would be searched inside the package of the class (returned by getClass()), basically the same location of the corresponding .class file

(usually the IDE or building tool have some settings specifying which directory used for source files and resources, and, when compiling/building, the resource files are copied to the same build directories as the .class files)

Try leaving the first line seperator away. like
    InputStream birdImageStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/flappybird.png");


Tried that, didn't work :(. Do you mind looking at my code to help me find what's wrong with it ?
